# prevent user to access specific pages after login with Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm working on a .Net application in which user can authenticate with a form using an Id or a Microsoft account (Azure Active Directory). The problem is that a user who doesn't yet have an account on my application can still connect via AD. After authentication, I would like to redirect him to a registration page for his account to be approved first. Since he is already authenticated, is there a way to prevent access to other pages?

I need some help, Thank you.

Comment: You could add a flag on the user's session that they are not an approved account. Or you could add a claim on their identity stored in the cookie that says the same thing. Then you can base authorization on that.

Comment: Thank you @juunas for your reply. But how can base authorization on claims since my application is not MVC?

Comment: Classic ASP.NET?

Comment: yes @juunas. Do you have an idea of ​​how to do it ? please